# Question about Cost in Oracle Explain Plan

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, optimization

When Oracle is estimating the 'Cost' for certain queries, does it actually look at the amount of data (rows) in a table?

For example:

If I'm doing a full table scan of employees for name='Bob', does it estimate the cost by counting the amount of existing rows, or is it always a set cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the default configuration, Oracle will check the table statistics (which you can look at by querying the `ALL_TABLES` view - see the column `NUM_ROWS`). Normally an Oracle job is run periodically to re-gather these statistics by querying part or all of the table.

If the statistics haven't been gathered (yet), the optimizer will (depending on the `optimizer_dynamic_sampling` parameter) run a quick sample query on the table in order to calculate an estimate for the number of rows in that table.

(To be more accurate, the cost of scanning a table is calculated not from the number of rows, but the number of blocks in the table (which you can see in the `BLOCKS` column in `ALL_TABLES`). It takes this number and divides it by a factor related to the multi-block read count to calculate the cost of that part of the plan.)

Answer (score 4):

The cost optimizer uses segment (table and index) statistics as well as system (cpu + i/o performance) statistics for the estimates.  Although it depends on how your database is configured, from 10g onwards the segment statistics are usually computed once per day by a process that is calling the DBMS_STATS package.